# Provable `fun-ext`and "rewriting under binders" in intensional MLTT

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, functional-extensionality

I've noticed that the underlying judgemental machinery of intensional MLTT can be extended such that function extensionality becomes provable. Or in other words it becomes possible to "rewrite under binders". I came up with the idea when working on a rewrite tactic for *extensional* MLTT. Given a goal type, a path to a sub-expression inside the goal type, and a proof-term the tactic rewrites the sub-expression according to the proof-term (just replaces one side with another). What's interesting is that the proof-term can depend on the binders we pass by when moving along the path to the sub-expression. In intensional MLTT `J` plays a role similar to that tactic. But it can't rewrite inside binders (unless the term we are rewriting doesn't depend on the bound variables).

Here is what we can do to make `J` as powerful as that tactic:

We enhance the *contexts* of type theory to hold *families of types* instead of just types.

Here is what the `J` rule looks like now:

```
Γ ⊦ Δ ctx
Γ Δ ⊦ A type
Γ Δ ⊦ a₀ : A
Γ (Δ ⊦ α : A) (Δ ⊦ β : a₀ ≡ α) ⊦ B type
Γ ⊦ r : B(a₀, Refl)
Γ Δ ⊦ a₁ : A
Γ Δ ⊦ a : a₀ ≡ a₁
----------------------------------------------------
Γ ⊦ J δ.A δ.a₀ (α(δ). β(δ). B) r δ.a₁ δ.a : B(δ.a₁, δ.a)
Γ ⊦ J δ.A δ.a₀ (α(δ). β(δ). B) r δ.a₀ δ.Refl = r : B(δ.a₀, δ.Refl)
```

`fun-ext` is derivable:

```
Γ ⊦ A type
Γ (x : A) ⊦ B type
Γ ⊦ f : (x : A) → B
Γ ⊦ g : (x : A) → B
Γ ⊦ p : (x : A) → f x ≡ g x
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fun-ext A (x. B) f g p ≔ J (x. B) (x. f x) (α(x). β(x). (x ↦ f x) ≡ (x ↦ α(x))) Refl (x. g x) (x. p x) : f ≡ g
```

Canonicity is lost in that case. But as we mostly care about canonicity for computational purposes, we can interpret terms of our intensional MLTT as terms of extensional MLTT. Erase `J` and here we go, we get canonicity w.r.t. the equational theory of extensional MLTT (which is enough to view the extended intensional MLTT as a programming language).

I'd love to get a professional opinion on the construction. Does it make sense? Do you see any obvious problems with it?

Comment: Does `≡` stand for the identity type or judgemental equality? What is `δ`?

Comment: You should explain what `Γ (Δ ⊦ α : A) (Δ ⊦ β : a₀ ≡ α) ⊦ B type` is supposed to mean. What is a context, precisely? What are the judgement forms? You're changing these notions in a fundamental way, so you should explain the changes.

Comment: `≡` stands for the identity type, like in Agda. Regarding `δ`:
just like we use the notation `x. t` to stand for a family `t` in the background context extended by some `x : ?`, I have `δ.t` standing for a family `t` in the background context extended by a telescope `δ : ?`. In that particular case `δ : Δ`.

A context is a snoc-list of families of types (where families can depend on preceding families). Families can be eliminated just like variables in normal MLTT, but now we need to provide an instance of the context the family depends on.

Comment: Of course there is a lot to it, but hopefully that conveys the idea. All that's new is that we replace dependence on type `(x : A)` with dependence on family `(Δ ⊦ x : A)`

Comment: I vaguely remember that Mike Shulman at some point was asking & thinking about having such multi-level contexts. Is he listening?

Comment: Hm, Can I tag him here? I don't think one can tag a user in a comment unless the user has participated in the discussion.

Comment: Hmm, isn't your idea more or less a multi-argument combination of ordinary `J` and ordinary `funext`? In the ordinary `funext` we have just one variable to abstract over, and in ordinary `J` the telescope `Δ` is empty, whereas  you allow a whole telescope. I would expect that your version of `J` (pleae don't call it `J`) is admissible with respect to the ordinary `J` and the ordinary `funext`.

Comment: What should I call it? :)

Comment: Indeed, I just tried it myself, I can prove a single-argument version of new `J` from old `J` & `fun-ext`. But for me it is still like chicken and egg situation. You can prove extensionality principle for every other standard type former via `J` but not `fun-ext`... I was thinking, maybe `J` was "wrong"...
Maybe there is something else interesting about multi-level contexts other than making fun-ext admissible.

Comment: Even if there is nothing else interesting, the new construction feels more satisfying somehow, as it encompasses fun-ext without extra axioms?

Comment: BTW, seriously, what's wrong with calling `J` a `J`? Am I mixing up names? Or is it about type-theory community wanting to phase the name out and replace with something else? Or did you mean I shouldn't call the new `J` a `J`?   :P

Comment: You should not call it 'J' (taken by Martin-Löf) or `K` (taken by Streicher). There are still some letters left in the alphabet. It was already a bit annoying that in my comment above I had to write "your `J`" and "ordinary `J`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new rule seems to be equivalent to funext plus the definitional equality that says that funext of constant `refl` is `refl`. As such, I don't see any issue with it. As you say equality reflection implies the new rule.

The higher-order assumptions aren't too problematic. If we have universes, we can rephrase them as plain functions. But I don't see a good reason to use the modified `J` rule. I like it better when eliminators of type formers make sense separately and follow a specification from some universal property, and extra axioms can be added on the top of that.

Comment: But maybe if we reformulate type theory via the "family of types" contexts instead of "plain types" contexts the new `J` would reflect some universal property?

Comment: @Russoul: Maybe. The burden on proof is on the person suggesting that there is such a thing.